# create dynamically mongo collection in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

create dynamically mongo collection in mongoose. I tried below code: suggest me please

```
function residenceModel(regionName){
  const residenceSchema = new Schema({
                key:String,
                value:String
            }, { strict: false });

  return mongoose.model(
          `residence_meta_${regionName}`,
           residenceSchema,
          `residence_meta_${regionName}`
       );
}

console.log(residenceModel);

exports.ResidenceModel = residenceModel;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create dynamic model with this simple steps

create a file dynamicModel.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
//import mongoose from 'mongoose'
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const dynamicModel = (regionName) => {
 const residenceSchema = new Schema({
                key:String,
                value:String
            }, { strict: false })
  return mongoose.model(
            `residence_meta_${regionName}`,
            residenceSchema,
            `residence_meta_${regionName}`
        );
}
module.exports = { dynamicModel }
// export default { dynamicModel }
```

On file where you want to include or create model let's say `app.js`

```
// Please take care of path
const { dynamicModel }  = require("./dynamicModel")
//import { dynamicModel } from "./dynamicModel";
.....
.....
// User this method to create model and use It
const countryModel = dynamicModel("country")
countryModel.create({ key:"country", value:"USA" });
```

Use this method multiple time, Give it a shot and let me know

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue. below is the code. you guys can use it.

```
function createMetaCollection(regionName) {
  console.log(regionName);
  var residenceSchema = new Schema(
    {
      region: String,
      customer_type: String,
    },
    { strict: false }
  );

  residenceSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, {
    model: "resident_meta_" + regionName,
    field: regionName + "id",
    startAt: 1,
  });

  exports.Typeof_employment_meta = mongoose.model(
    "resident_meta_" + regionName,
    residenceSchema,
    "resident_meta_" + regionName
  );
}
```